# Copying binary jpg data into a buffer

Tags: c++

```
void jpgToBuff(const char* srcfilename)
{

    FILE* file = fopen(srcfilename, "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long fileLen = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* file_data;
    file_data = (char *)malloc((fileLen + 1) * sizeof(char));
    fread(file_data, fileLen, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Am I doing this correctly. I want to eventually send this information through a socket and decode it on the other side. Any suggestions would be super helpful. Is this theoretically possible to send this through a socket and decode it into an image on the other side?

Comment: Explaining the problems you are seeing would help in getting a better answer

Comment: change your title, it is confusing

Comment: You don't need +1 for binary data, but otherwise it should read the file into the buffer.  It's very hard to tell what sort of answer you're looking for here.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to send data over a network? Yes, yes it is.

Comment: I don't think folk use `malloc()` any more with C++. And I think they use `unique_ptr` too. And `stat()` will tell you the length of the file in a single function call.

Comment: This piece of C code is perfect example of how you should not attempt to use C++. In C++, you'd use `std::string`, `std::ifstream` and `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: A `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char>` would do you no good, as it would manage a single character. You'd use `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Maybe post an answer to illustrate good, modern C++ practice so we all learn something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're not doing enough error checking. fopen, fseek, ftell, malloc, fread and fclose can all fail. Failures would likely result in a crash or other unexpected results.

fread might return fewer characters than you attempted to read, so you should probably check for that too.

You've allocated +1 byte, presumably so you could add a terminating '\0'? But you left that final byte uninitialized. A jpeg file could reasonably contain an embedded '\0', so adding a terminating '\0' is probably not going to get you the results you're hoping for.

Finally, sizeof(char) is defined by the standards to be 1, always. So, you might as well multiply by 1, or better yet, don't.

Other than that it looks basically right.